# Cláusulas adjetivas que comienzan con "que más..."

Tags: gramática, superlativos

He encontrado algunas cláusulas adjetivas que comienzan con "que más + adjetivo" o "que más + sustantivo".  ¿Es otra forma de expresar el superlativo?

Ej: El Pad Thai es seguramente uno de los platos de la cocina tailandesa **que más popular se ha hecho en occidente.**  ([original](https://directiatravel.com/mx/viajes-tailandia/guia/consejos/comida-tipica))

Ej: Su primer modelo, el Lucid Air Dream Edition, ha sido reconocido como el "carro del año" por la revista especializada MotorTrend y, según datos de la Agencia de Protección Ambiental de Estados Unidos, es el auto eléctrico **que más distancia puede recorrer con una sola carga: unas 520 millas (852 kilómetros).** ([original](https://www.bbc.com/mundo/noticias-59341293))

Me interesa esta formulación y quiero leer sobre su uso. ¿Cuál es el término adecuado para referirse a ella?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Se llaman *construcciones superlativas complejas*, y se tratan en el [§ 45.13ñ](http://aplica.rae.es/grweb/cgi-bin/v.cgi?i=SGNSxgkYzSQgwWKS) y siguientes de la *Nueva Gramática de la Lengua Española* (NGLE). Son, efectivamente, oraciones subordinadas adjetivas.

Estas construcciones son necesarias siempre que se quiere indicar un superlativo con un verbo que no sea el verbo *ser*. Véase la diferencia entre las construcciones superlativas con el verbo *ser* y con el verbo *comer*:

- Juan es el (alumno) *más alto* (de la clase).
- Juan es el (alumno) *que más (dulces) ha comido* (de la clase).

(Las partes entre paréntesis se pueden omitir y las frases siguen siendo correctas). Como dice la NGLE ([§ 45.13p](http://aplica.rae.es/grweb/cgi-bin/v.cgi?i=buzSCpczRWKpNgLw)), el superlativo también puede ir después del verbo:

- Juan es el (alumno) que ha comido *más (dulces)* (de la clase).

No hay otra manera de hacer una construcción superlativa con verbos distintos de *ser*, es decir, las siguientes construcciones no son válidas:

- Juan ha comido [<del>el que más</del>/<del>lo más</del>/...].

El mismo significado se puede expresar con una construcción comparativa simple:

- Juan ha comido más que [nadie/ningún otro].